# goog.dom.query TypeError in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript, google-closure-library

I'm trying to use [goog.dom.query](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/closure_third_party_closure_goog_dojo_dom_query.js.html) from ClojureScript.

```
(:require [goog.dom.query :as q])

…

(q/query ".foo.bar")
```

produces the following error in the JS console at runtime:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function $o(a,b){if(!a)return[];if(a.constructor==Array)return a;if(!ia(a))return[a];if(ia(b)&&(b=ia(b)?document.getElementById(b):b,!b))return[];var b=b||document,c=b.ownerDocument||b.documentElement;xo=b.contentType&&"application/xml"==b.contentType||dk&&(b.doctype||"[object XMLDocument]"==c.toString())||!!c&&(ek?c.xml:b.xmlVersion||c.xmlVersion);return(c=Wo(a)(b))&&c.Bb?c:Zo(c)} has no method 'Ja'
```

EDIT: I get the error even from just requiring it.

Comment: After I compile with pretty print (not from clojurescript but JS code using goog.dom.query) there is a comment in the code `Portions of this code are from the Dojo Toolkit, received by` Do you have those comments in your code? I suspect somehow the 3rd party libraries are not included but don't understand why code is generated at all and no error is thrown during compilation.

Comment: This is library is not in the goog directory, you can find goog.dom.query in third_party...dojo and deps.js should have a reference to it. Not sure how it would compile though if that reference was missing. In the closure library there should be a file: `third_party\closure\goog\dojo\dom\query_test.html` you can open that file and see if the unit tests pass for goog.dom.query.

Comment: I do have those comments in the JS file, @HMR.

Answer (score 2):

[Comments](http://docs.closure-library.googlecode.com/git/local_third_party_closure_goog_dojo_dom_query.js.source.html#line196) in the source code mark this function as deprecated and recommend using [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead:

`(.querySelector js/document ".foo.bar")`

> *@deprecated* This is an all-software query selector. Use
>   document.querySelector. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector .

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, query is not available by default in goog.dom. 
Here's how you can use it anyhow:

```
(ns cljs-dom.core
  (:import [goog.dom query])
  (:require [goog.dom :as gdom]))
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
(.log js/console (aget (query ".myClass") 0))
```

`gdom` is included here as a convenience. You can write `gdom/createElement` and all the other standard calls. If you only need `query`, it is not required.